# Making Google Sign-In Work in a Web2py Application

Tags: web2py

I have been using Web2py for a little less than a month. I have an app/website that I made using Web2py that utilizes Python and HTML/CSS. It's very similar to the app that Massimo made in his week 1 tutorial video for Web2py. **I am currently using the default login/sign up registration system that comes with Web2py. The problem I am having is that I am VERY lost in figuring out how to make Google Sign-In my login/sign up registration system instead of the default.** I am not sure how to do this.

The Access and Control chapter of the Web2py manual states that "**authentication using Google when running on Google App Engine requires skipping the web2py login form, being redirected to the Google login page, and back upon success.**" It then gives 2 lines of code:

```
from gluon.contrib.login_methods.gae_google_login import GaeGoogleAccount
auth.settings.login_form = GaeGoogleAccount()
```

When I implement this code after (auth being defined) in db.py, I get an internal error in my Web2py application that tells me that `<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>(No module named gae_google_login)` I'm very confused on what to do. I was told that I just needed to add/modify 3 lines of code and it would somehow work.

I just want to get Google Sign-In to work and I can't really find a straight forward tutorial on how to go about this. Does anyone have any tips/advice? I am using the default db.py file that came with Web2py.

Answer (score 1):

The book is incorrect -- the name of the module is `gae_google_account` (not `gae_google_login`. You'll also need `google.appengine.api` installed.

Of course, the above is only relevant if you are running your application on Google Appengine. Otherwise, if you want to enable Google sign-in, you can either follow the OAuth 2.0 instructions [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Other-login-methods-and-login-forms), or use the built-in [Janrain functionality](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Integration-with-OpenID--Facebook--etc-).

Comment: Thanks! Also, how do you install the google.appengine.api? Is it basically just downloading and installing GAE?

Comment: Yes, I believe it should come with the Python SDK. You should also be able to install the [API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) by itself.